# rally.ui.renderer.template is not displaying the data

Tags: rally

I have created a data store and a data model in the Rally app builder. I want to display some of the defect fields in a Rally grid from the defect model and I want to use the Rally renderer to format them. In my grid defintion, I have:

```
        columnCfgs: [
        {
            xtype: 'templatecolumn',
            text: 'ID',
            width: 100,
            tpl: Ext.create('Rally.ui.renderer.template.FormattedIDTemplate')
        },
        {
            xtype: 'templatecolumn',
            text: 'Creation Date',
            tpl: Ext.create('Rally.ui.renderer.template.DateTemplate', {the: 'CreationDate'})
        },
        {
            text: 'Name',
            dataIndex: 'Name',
            flex: 1
        },
        {
            text: 'Schedule State',
            xtype: 'templatecolumn',
            tpl: Ext.create('Rally.ui.renderer.template.ScheduleStateTemplate',
                {field: 'ScheduleState'}
                )
        }, ...
```

The formatted Id and the name display with no problems but the creation date and schedule state fields do not display. I cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong. If I remove the renderer templates from these fields and just display the values, the values will display. But the renderer templates are not working for some reason. Any suggestions? Thanks.